# Obtener el valor de un campo con Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Quiero obtener el valor del campo `extension` y poder utilizarlo en una variable pero me marca error. Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
var ext = (from ex in ctx.usuarios_bastion where ex.id == idus select ex).ToList().ToString();
            string completeName = idus.ToString()+ext.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si es un solo dato, de un solo registro de la tabla usuarios_bastion, tienes que especificarlo:

```
var ext = (from ex in ctx.usuarios_bastion where ex.id == idus select ex).First().NombreDelCampo;
string completeName = idus.ToString()+ext.ToString();
```